# Sort values inside an Array on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array on php:

```
Array ( [googlewindow] => 1 [google] => 6 [kei] => 1 [uutntpzlfcewtgfer] => 2 [dbq] => 2 [kexpi] => 1 [kcsi] => 1 [e] => 8 [ei] => 1 [expi] => 1 [ml] => 1 [function] => 5 [khl] => 1 [es] => 1 [time] => 2 [return] => 1 [new] => 3 [date] => 2 [gettime] => 2 [log] => 1 [b] => 2 [d] => 2 [c] => 6 [var] => 5 [a] => 12 [image] => 1 [g] => 3 [lc] => 2 [f] => 4 [li] => 3 [onerror] => 1 [onload] => 1 [onabort] => 1 [delete] => 1 [gen] => 1 [atyp] => 1 [i] => 1 [ct] => 1 [cad] => 1 [zx] => 1 [src] => 1 [toolbelt] => 1 [window] => 3 [sn] => 1 [webhp] => 1 [timers] => 1 [load] => 1 [t] => 1 [start] => 1 [try] => 1 [catch] => 1 [u] => 1 [jsrt] => 1 [kill] => 1 [gjwl] => 3 [location] => 1 [gjuc] => 1 [href] => 2 [indexof] => 4 [if] => 3 [substring] => 2 [q] => 2 [-] => 1 [for] => 1 )
```

How can i using a FOR or WHILE instruction sort from MAX to MIN and then print the result? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at [**asort()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php):

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their correlation with the array elements they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.

PHP has many [**built in array sorting functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: The point of PHP, with its mass of built-in functions, is to use them instead of coding it yourself, which will almost always be slower/less efficient.